# Rug plot in TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I wish to draw something like (a kind of rug plot)
[image]

The plot shows performance of various machine learning methods. I wonder what is the best way to draw perpendicular hooks. Moreover, how can I  automatize hook drawing.

Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Minimal working example is pasted below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

% Axis
\draw[-] (0,0) -- (5,0);
% Coordinates
\node (A) at (3,0) {};
\node (B) at (2,0) {};
\node (C) at (2.5,0) {};

% Lines
\draw (A) -| ++(0,-0.5)-| ++(2,0) node (n1) [right] {LDA};
\draw (B) -| ++(0,-0.5)-| ++(-2,0) node (n2) [left] {RF};
\draw (C) -| ++(0,-1)-| ++(-2.5,0) node (n2) [left] {SVM};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide with a full example (including `\documentclass{article}` etc.)

Comment: Search the [`pgf` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) for `-|` and `|-`, the vertical/horizontal (and vice-versa) line operations.

Comment: I'll provide current code as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm perplexed. Why is this a "rug plot"?

Comment: @Andrew: please suggest the right name.

Comment: I have no idea! I was just curious as I thought there may have been a reason or story behind the name. From the title I was hoping to see something like a Persian rug:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty solution for your problem. All the information you need can also be taken easily from the *pgfmanual* as stated above.

The solution is based on using coordinates for the interesting points. This way the code can be reused easily with other values.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
  lbl/.style={
    text width=1.5cm,
  },
 }
 % axis
 \draw (1,0) -- (4,0);
 \foreach \x [count=\i] in {1,...,4} {
  \draw (\x, 0) -- ++(0,.1) node [above] {\i};
  \ifthenelse{\x < 4}{\draw (\x+.5, 0) -- ++(0,.05);}{}
 }

 % coordinates
 \coordinate (c0) at (1,0);
 \coordinate (c1) at (1.8,0);
 \coordinate (c2) at (2.75,0);
 \coordinate (c3) at (3.2,0);
 \coordinate (c4) at (3.3,0);
 \coordinate (c5) at (4,0);

 % cd
 \draw [|-|] ($(c0) +(0,.75)$) -- ($(c1) +(0,.75)$) node [midway, above] {CD};

 % labels
 \node (l1) at (c0) [below left=.25cm and 0cm, lbl, align=right] {first};
 \node (l2) [below=0cm of l1, lbl, align=right] {second};
 \node (l4) at (c5) [below right=.25cm and 0cm, lbl, align=left] {fourth};
 \node (l3) [below=0cm of l4, lbl,  align=left] {third};

 % connectors
 \foreach \x in {1,...,4} {
  \draw (l\x) -| (c\x);
 };
 \draw [ultra thick] ($(c2)+(-.1,-.25)$) -- ($(c4)+(.1,-.25)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered image]